# Confluent rest prozy basic authentication doesn't work

Tags: apache-kafka, jaas, kafka-rest, confluent-rest-proxy

I am trying to configure simple authentication for rest proxy for Kafka cluster
[repo with dockerfile](https://github.com/zloodeyka/kafkasasl) but cannot login to rest proxy.

I used [this](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/production-deployment/rest-proxy/security.html#http-basic-authentication) documentation to configure authentication.
Cluster described in docker-compose.yml file runs successfully but when I try lo login in localhost:8082/topics/ with browser using *thisismyusername* username and *thisismypass* password I got nothing. I assume that authentication was failed. How is it possible to fix that?

Comment: Please include your code in the post itself... Typo? This line should have leading slash /etc  https://github.com/zloodeyka/kafkasasl/blob/main/configs/rest-jaas.properties#L4